# How do I open a file if I only know part of the file name?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to open a file whose full filename I do not know.

I know the file name is something like.

```
filename*esy
```

I know definitely that there's only one occurrence of this file in the given directory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`filename*esy` is already a "shell ready" wildcard & if thats alway the case you can simply;

```
const SOME_PATH as string = "c:\rootdir\"
...
Dim file As String
file = Dir$(SOME_PATH & "filename*esy" & ".*")

If (Len(file) > 0) Then
  MsgBox "found " & file
End If
```

Just call (or loop until empty) `file = Dir$()` to get the next match.

Answer (score 2):

```
If InStr(sFilename, "filename") > 0 and InStr(sFilename, "esy") > 0 Then
 'do somthing
end if
```

Or you can use RegEx

```
 Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object 

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 
    With RE 
        .MultiLine = False 
        .Global = False 
        .IgnoreCase = True 
        .Pattern = "filename(.*)esy" 
    End With 

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(sFilename) 
    REMatches(0) 'find match
```

Comment: for some reason i was assuming the file was open. oops

Answer (score 2):

There is an `Application.FileSearch` you can use (see below). You could use that to search for the files that match your pattern. This information taken from [here](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/06/search-and-open-files-using-excel-vba.html).

```
Sub App_FileSearch_Example()

    With Application.FileSearch
        .NewSearch
        .LookIn = "c:\some_folder\"
        .FileName = "filename*esy"
        If .Execute(SortBy:=msoSortByLastModified, SortOrder:=msoSortOrderDescending) > 0 Then    
            For i1 = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
                ' do something with matched file(s)
            Next i1

        End If

    End With    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying this question as a function.  This is the solution that ended up working for me.

```
Function fileName(path As String, sName As String, ext As String) As Variant

'path is Full path from root.  Can also use path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
'sName is the string to search. ? and * are wildcards.  ? is for single char
'example sName = "book?" or sName ="March_*_2014*"
'ext is file extention ie .pdf .xlsm .xls? .j*

Dim file As Variant 'Store the next result of Dir
Dim fname() As String 'Dynamic Array for result set
ReDim fname(0 To 0) 
Dim i As Integer ' Counter
i = 0

' Use dir to search and store first result
fname(i) = path & Dir(path & "\" & sName & ext) 
i = i + 1

'Load next result
file = Dir 

While file <> "" 'While a file is found store that file in the array
  ReDim Preserve fname(0 To i) As String
  fname(i) = path & file
  file = Dir
Wend

fileName = Application.Transpose(fname) 'Print out array

 End Function
```

This works for me as a single or array function.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that no other file contains "filename" and "esy" in that order then you can simply use

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "Filepath\filename*esy.*"
```

Or if you know the number of missing characters then (assuming 4 characters unknown)

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "Filepath\filename????esy.*"
```

I use this method to run code on files which are date & timestamped to ignore the timestamp part.