# Access 2016 VBA code to import files with variable names

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use Access VBA to automate the import (by the push of a button) of daily files that exist in a format like this:

```
Final_Data_ver20181101063035.xlsx
```

where the numeric piece translates as: yyyymmddhhmmss.

However, without knowing exactly what time the file was created, Access can't find it. I've been trying something like:

```
Dim datepiece as String
Dim file as String

datepiece = format(Date,"yyyymmdd")
file = "c:\Users\brian\Final_Data_ver" & datepiece & "*" & ".xlsx"
```

But I keep getting errors when I try this. It's looking for a file literally named:

```
Final_Data_ver20181102*.xlsx
```

Maybe I'm just not able to use wildcards in a statement like this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `Debug.Print Dir(file)` should return the first name which matches that pattern.  Can you use that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i open a file if i only know part of the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860797/how-do-i-open-a-file-if-i-only-know-part-of-the-file-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how you could find all files like `Final_Data_ver20181102*.xlsx` in Folder `c:\`:

```
Sub Test()
    Const TEMPLATE As String = "c:\Final_Data_ver20181102*.xlsx"

    Dim filename As String
    filename = Dir(TEMPLATE)
    Do
        If filename = vbNullString Then Exit Do
        'Instead of just printing the filename you can use it to import it like you did before.
        Debug.Print filename
        filename = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```